# Eclipse jobs API+ newFixedThreadPool

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, plugins, jobs

I want to achieve below functionality using eclipse jobs API.

```
int nrOfProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService eservice =
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nrOfProcessors); eservice.submit(new
FilValidation());


I have 1000 files, and i want to run only 4 threads at a time using
Eclipse Jobs API and wanted to show the progress of 4 threads as
well.

As my per knowledge,for best performance we need to run the threads
which is close to number of cores in the system.


Best Regards, Kondal Kolipaka
```